# Importing the vaadin AbstractExtensionConnector class gives me an error in Eclipse

Tags: java, vaadin

I try to build a simple UI extension of the Vaadin `TextField` component. I created a Widgetset for this but when I try to import the `AbstractExtensionConnector` Vaadin class in my own connector class it gives me an import error. Actually, I cannot import anything starting with `com.vaadin.client....`.

Although, I can import other Vaadin classes in this connector class like this:

```
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.Connect;
```

This is the error message in Eclipse:

```
The import com.vaadin.client cannot be resolved
```

Can someone please tell me why it is not possible to include anything starting with `com.vaadin.client`?

Comment: If you solved it, please write it into the answer section, and accept it, as good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this dependecy in the pom.xml solved the problem:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId> 
    <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId> 
    <version>7.7.7</version> 
</dependency>
```